# Что означает метод route() и его параметры в данном случае?

Tags: java, маршрутизация, vert.x

В vert.x web изучая руты, наткнулся на такой код:

```
HttpServer server = Vertx.vertx().createHttpServer();
  Router router = Router.router(Vertx.vertx());

    Route route1 = router.route("/some/path/").handler(routingContext -> {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
        response.setChunked(true);
        response.write("route1\n");
        routingContext.vertx().setTimer(5000, tid -> routingContext.next());
    });

    Route route2 = router.route("/some/path/").handler(routingContext -> {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
        response.write("route2\n");
        routingContext.vertx().setTimer(5000, tid ->  routingContext.next());
    });

    Route route3 = router.route("/some/path/").handler(routingContext -> {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
        response.write("route3");
        routingContext.response().end();
    });

    server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080, new Handler<AsyncResult<HttpServer>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(AsyncResult<HttpServer> event) {
            if(event.succeeded()) System.out.println("server started");
            else System.out.println("server error");
        }
    });
```

Не могу понять за что отвечает метод route("/some/path/").В описании метода говорится:

```
Route route(String path);
    Add a route that matches the specified HTTP method and path regex
    @param method  the HTTP method to match
    @param regex  URI paths that begin with a match for this regex will match
    @return the route
```

Метод принимает строку(не понимаю,что это за строка,что в ней прописывается). Возвращает экземпляр интерфейса Route. Полез в него:

```
public interface Route {
    Add an HTTP method for this route. By default a route will match all HTTP methods. If any are specified then the route
    will only match any of the specified methods
    @param method  the HTTP method to add
    @return a reference to this, so the API can be used fluently
```

Понятней от этого увы не стало(Не исключаю того факта,что не до конца понимаю, что такое router  в данном случае. Исходя из всего вышепреведенного, подскажите пожалуйста,что происходит в этом методе и где можно по данной теме прочитать толковый материал

Comment: Router - это маршрутизатор. Route - маршрут (или путь). Router принимает решение по какому пути направлять входящий запрос. Каждый маршрут (route) регистрируется в маршрутизаторе с указанием какие запросы по нему посылать. Router смотрит на запрос, смотрит какие у него есть маршруты для этого запроса и посылает туда

Comment: Примерно понял.В данном коде Http-соединение. куда направляют эти 3 рутера?

Comment: Роутер один. А 3 - это руты, (маршруты, пути). Все они ведут каждый к своему обработчику handler-у. Обработчик что-то там делает по этому запросу, пишет что-то в ответ (response) и может завершить дальнейшие мытарства запроса или послать по следующему маршруту, который принимает данный запрос

Comment: значит я мог записать хендлеры для каждого маршрута свой. потом создать маршруты и каждому ткнуть соответствующий хендлер? и в зависимости от указанного пути, клиентские запросы будут отправляться этим хендлерам?

Comment: @lga да так. (это чтобы мессага не выглядела короткой)

Comment: вас не затруднит перетащить 2 сообщение про рутер из комментария в отдельный ответ на вопрос,чтобы я его отметил и закрыл этот вопрос?

Comment: Можете сами ответить на свой вопрос. Как сами поняли. Практически я ни с вертехом, ни с чем-либо другим где явно присутствует понятие маршрутов дел не имел. Изредка только заметки почитаешь, да и подход этот понятен (может потому что много работал админом/сетивиком).

Comment: хорошо. просто в таком случае, я не смогу повысить вашу репутацию,за счет обозначения вашего ответа как правильный. сейчас сам попробую описать все. спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Итак, разобравшись немного, попробую сам же ответить на данный вопрос(мало ли,может кому пригодится). В данном случае у нас есть рутер, от которого вытягиваются  3 маршрута для подключаемого клиента. у каждого маршрута есть свой хендлер, который включается,когда клиент,переходит по соответствующему адресу. к примеру  у нас на рутере есть 3 возможных маршрута(к примеру возьмем какой-то сайт):

```
Route route1 =router.route("/registration/")

Route route2 = router.route("/gallery/")

Route route3 = router.route("/video/")
```

а внизу в коде, перед `listen()` у нас есть такая штучка `requestHandler(router::accept)`(как я понимаю, грубо говоря, установка рутера на сервер). итак, клиент указывает адрес mysite.com/registration. сервер принимает это дело и смотрит есть ли такой маршрут. если есть, то включается хендлер, который дает сигнал на соответствующую обработку запроса(в хендлере уже может быть реализован механизм регистрации пользователя). в случае запроса с другими путями, клиент будет попадать в галерею и видеоархив. в конечном итоге метод `route("/video/")` принимает путь, который мы хотим прописать в руте. как-то так. немного коряво, но я думаю,что суть уловил...